# How does Live Painting skill work?

Tags: persona-5

I don't understand how to use Live Painting skill of Yusuke. Text says:

> Allows Yusuke to use Card Duplication and Card Creation on the spot.

But how do I activate it? It doesn't show up in the skills menu.

I know I can activate card Creation and Duplication by talking to him at the train station, but if I understand correctly I should be able to create and duplicate cards even in the Metaverse with this skill. How so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be how the descriptions are translated, causing a slight ambiguity on the meaning of the skills. Based on [this guide](https://samurai-gamers.com/persona-5/emperor-confidant-yusuke-kitagawa/), both Card Duplication and Card Creation require 1 full day for Yusuke to create the skill cards.

The Live Painting skill reduces the amount of time required for the skill cards to be created. So you still need to visit Yusuke at the train station, but rather than awaiting a full day, he can create the skill cards immediately.